# How to sort a time-based column without time column in groupby object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df_yes = pd.DataFrame({
   'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
   'time_1' :['2173-04-03 12:35:00','2173-04-03 12:50:00','2173-04-03 
  12:59:00','2173-04-03 13:14:00','2173-04-03 13:37:00','2173-04-03 
  13:39:00','2173-04-04 11:30:00','2173-04-05 16:00:00','2173-04-05 
  22:00:00','2173-04-06 04:00:00','2173-04-06 04:30:00','2173-04-06 
  08:00:00'],
   'val' :[5,5,5,5,1,6,5,5,8,3,4,6]
    })
df_yes['time_1']= pd.to_datetime(df_yes['time_1'])
```

What I am trying to do is get the `count` and `cumduration` of a specific value in a day. For which I have written the below code

```
s=pd.to_timedelta(24,unit='h')-(df_yes.time_1-df_yes.time_1.dt.normalize())
df_yes['tdiff'] = df_yes.groupby(df_yes.time_1.dt.date).time_1.diff().shift(-1).fillna(s)
df_yes['t_d'] = df_yes['tdiff'].dt.total_seconds()/3600
df_yes['hr'] = df_yes['time_1'].dt.hour
df_yes['min'] = df_yes['time_1'].dt.minute
df_yes['date'] = df_yes['time_1'].dt.date
df_yes['day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df_yes['time_1']).day
## the below code is where I get the count and cum duration of a specific value in day for each hour
pd.DataFrame(df_yes.groupby(['date','hr','val'])['t_d'].agg({'cumduration':sum,'freq':'count'}).reset_index())
```

It produces the output as shown below

[image]

As you can see , it has messed up the time-order. I mean the first value to occur on `13th hour of 2173-04-03` was `5` but it shows as `1`. If you see the time information in my dataframe, you will get an idea. I didn't use the `minute` information in group by clause because it will not allow me to group the values based on hours. Hope this info helps

I expect my output to be ordered based on time. You can see how it is arranged based on time components.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `sort=False` into your groupby line (shown below)

```
pd.DataFrame(df_yes.groupby(['date','hr','val'], sort=False)['t_d'].agg({'cumduration':sum,'freq':'count'}).reset_index())
```